# Family members traveling with me: DS-160 query

Tags: usa, visa, family

I will be applying for a nonimmigrant F-1 student visa and I'm currently filling out my DS-160 form. My parents plan to travel with me on tourist visas. They do not have a US visa at this point however, and will need to apply for tourist visas soon. My parents have booked tickets, both for arrival and for their return. We'll be going together and they'll be returning back to my home country after some time.

I have a doubt regarding the question which asks me to state if there are other persons traveling with me. I have typed out a 'yes' since my family members will accompany me and they will return back after some time. But they do not have visas yet, and I was wondering if it is a necessity for them to take their visa interviews along with me.

I've already booked my OFC and consular appointments. My parents have not started their applications for tourist visas as yet. I am aware that a family planning to go to the US together can book a family appointment together, but since I'm not too sure as to when my parents will find it suitable to take their appointments, I would not like to book a family appointment. More importantly, I do not think that they would now get the same visa dates that I now have. Would my situation be fine?

Answer (score 1):

The plan is that your parents will accompany you when you travel to the US, booking the same flights; you'll enter school and set up residence, they'll go home in several weeks.

In your visa application, respond 'yes,' you would be accompanied, that your parents plan to travel with you to help you settle in. Add an explanatory note, that they are applying, separately, for their visas, describe their planned itinerary. Discuss it during your interview.

Your family members should answer 'yes' to the same, or similar, questions in their visa applications, explain the circumstances, and discuss during their interview.

Your interview and theirs would be scheduled separately.